# TexStudio not generating PDF on Mac

Tags: pdf, texstudio

Writing my dissertation currently on TexStudio. Deleted PDF and stopped compiling when both "Build & View"/"Compile" are pressed. Unsure why.

Log shows: "Fatal Error occured, no PDF file produced!"

Issues shows: "File ended while scanning use of @xdblarg."

Also at the bottom of the PDF viewer in TexStudio it says "Failed to find file '', perhaps it has been deleted"

Have tried deleting all other auxiliary files, cleaning log, re-installing software, checked compiler.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You have an error in you latex code. Figure out where `File ended while scanning use of @xdblarg` and fix it. There is likely no need to reinstall software,  this more seems to be a user error. You do not provide any code, we cannot help any further.

Comment: I suppose that there is a missing `}` in your code. LaTeX searches for a corresponding closing parentheses and reached the file end.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP reported that the issue was closed in the comment section, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/519936/128553.